# Merge two arrays in PHP without changing the structure of the first array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

```
$arr1 = array('foo'=>array('green'=>10, 'flowers'=>20), 'bar'=>20);
$arr2 = array('red'=>'roses', 'blue'=>'sky', foo=>array('flowers'=>15), 'bar'=>array('demo'=>'asdf'));
```

Desired result of the merge:

```
array('foo'=>array('green'=>10, 'flowers'=>15), 'bar'=>array('demo'=>'asdf'));
```

I have written a recursive function for this purpose, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way in PHP to achieve this.

This is my function:

```
function array_overwrite_recursive($arr1, $arr2) {
    foreach($arr1 As $k=>$v) {
        if(is_array($arr1[$k])) {
            $arr1[$k] = array_overwrite_recursive($arr1[$k], $arr2[$k]);
        } else {
            if(isset($arr2[$k])) $arr1[$k]=$arr2[$k];
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```